# One To Many relationship - Parent child definition

Tags: database-design, parent-child

I'm studying database design using some paper provided as material for the course.
I've found following explanation:

Let us consider table ***A*** and table ***B***. If there is a **One to Many** relation between ***A*** and ***B***, then (almost) each record of ***A*** has a direct link with a variable number of records of ***B***, whereas, (almost) each record of ***B*** has a direct link with a single record of ***A***.

> In other words, ***A*** descend from ***B*** and so, ***B*** could be
> named as the “Father Table” and ***A*** could be named as the “Son”
> one.

In my understanding last sentence is wrong; I'd modify to:

> In other words, ***B*** descend from ***A*** and so, ***A*** could be
> named as the “Father Table” and ***B*** could be named as the “Son”
> one

Is it correcy my doubt about the error in the provided text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the text is correct. Table B provides the values for table A and should be called the "Father" table. Without table B, you don't have any value to set in table A.